# How to add variable + databinding to ASP.NET link navigateurl?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Let's say I have a repeater with the code:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileLeafRef")%>'>
        <h2><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title")%></h2>     
    </asp:HyperLink>                
</ItemTemplate>
```

The FileLeadRef variable only contains the page name though (like test.aspx and not the full URL which I need). I can get the first part of the URL in a variable in page_load so I need to do something like:

`NavigateUrl='<%myVariable + "/"%><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileLeafRef")%>'` but it obviously doesn't work and a have tried a few varieties without success.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

```
<%# myVariable + "/" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileLeafRef")%>
```

Comment: With that I get the name 'siteUrl' does not exist in the current context so I must be missing something.

Comment: @user: Make it a field in the class.

Answer (score 0):

I usually move url construction in a code-behind function:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# UrlHelper(myVariable ,DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileLeafRef"))%>'>

protected string UrlHelper(string prefix, object leaf)
{
   return prefix + "/" + leaf.ToString();

}
```